# Injecting route values based on the current Principal

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I've got a web api that accepts authentication through either an api key, a user access token, or a client access token. I've already written a `DelegatingHandler` for each case, that creates a new `ClaimsPrincipal` based on the given authentication details, and have confirmed that the principal is accessible within a controller action.

What I want to do now is inject either a company, a user, or a publisher into the route values, so I can create overloads on the controller for each case. What class/interface do I need to extend in order to plug into the pipeline with the following conditions:

- Has access to the current principal
- Has access to the route data
- The action has not yet been selected

**Edit**

I'm not looking to sidestep routing here - I still want MVC to choose a route for me, based on the route values. I just want to add one more parameter to the route values before it chooses, and the parameter will have a different name and type depending on whether a user access token is used, or an api key is used.

I believe the subject of authentication should result in two distinct methods, because an api key can access all resources for a company, while a user access token can only access the resources they have been given permission to view.

Comment: Add it as a claim on the principal and retrieve it in the action from the identity

Comment: I have already added the claims to the principal. What I want now is to have three overloads of the action on the controller, and add a company, a user, or a publisher to the route values based on the authentication method used, to determine which overload is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see a reason why you would want to go with a controller here. You would be sidestepping routing, a very opinionated piece of MVC. I would [create middleware that runs before MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware) (which is, itself, just middleware) instead.

---

If you're looking to affect `RouteData` inline, I would look into using [a global `IResourceFilter` or `IAsyncResourceFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#resource-filters). Then, you can update [the `RouteData` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actioncontext#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ActionContext_RouteData) on the [`ResourceExecutingContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.resourceexecutingcontext) based upon the conditions you specified in your question.

Any additional dependencies you need to determine how to populate the `RouteData` property can be injected into the resource filter's constructor as specified in [the section on dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#dependency-injection).

```
public class SetRouteValueResourceFilter : IAsyncResourceFilter {

    public async Task OnResourceExecutionAsync(ResourceExecutingContext context, ResourceExecutionDelegate next) {
        var company = context.HttpContext.Identity.FindFirst("Company")?.Value;

        if (company != null) {
            context.RouteData.Values.Add("company", company);
        }

        await next();
    }

}
```

This answer is just an idea. Even though this is handled before the action logic, I'm not sure it will affect which route is selected. According to [this diagram](https://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf), routes are selected before filters are ran.

Comment: That's a very helpful diagram you have linked to. It looks like what I am after is a custom `ValueProviderFactory`, which will read the principal and return a `NameValueCollectionValueProvider` with the current user, company, or publisher.

Comment: I don't think that'll work. If you're still looking for two actions to the same route, how would MVC know you're sending a valid request to Action #1 instead of invalid request to Action #2? You're suggesting it should infer this by types and parameters names, which I do not believe it will do. I would be more explicit in which action, if any, you want handling the request. Check out [IActionConstraint](https://www.strathweb.com/2017/06/using-iactionconstraints-in-asp-net-core-mvc/)

Comment: We have gone with your suggestion of more specific routes, as route selection is only a problem for resources that do not belong directly to a company e.g. users. The company-specific resources require either a user access token _and_ a company id, generally as part of the route, which makes it distinguishable from the api key version. I think if a resource doesn't belong to a company, then an api key shouldn't have access to the resource - hopefully this assumption holds in the future, and is not too restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this going by making a custom `ValueProviderFactory`, which reads values from the current principal's claims and makes them available for parameter binding:

```
public class ClaimsPrincipalValueProviderFactory : ValueProviderFactory
{
    public override IValueProvider GetValueProvider(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.RequestContext.Principal != null && actionContext.RequestContext.Principal is ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            var pairs = principal.Claims.Select(claim => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(claim.Type, claim.Value));
            return new NameValuePairsValueProvider(pairs, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

In order to use it, you can annotate the input parameters with the `ValueProvider` attribute:

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public void Bar([ValueProvider(typeof(ClaimsPrincipalValueProviderFactory))]ApiKey apiKey)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

That's pretty ugly and unreadable, what I really wanted was something like the `FromUri` attribute, but for claims. `ValueProviderAttribute` and `FromUriAttribute` both inherit from `ModelBinderAttribute`, so I created a class which does the same:

```
/// <summary>
/// The action parameter comes from the user's claims, if the user is authorized.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class FromClaimsAttribute : ModelBinderAttribute
{
    public override HttpParameterBinding GetBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter)
    {
        return parameter.BindWithModelBinding(new ClaimsPrincipalValueProviderFactory());
    }
}
```

Now the example method on the `FooController` looks a lot more readable:

```
[HttpGet]
public void Bar([FromClaims]ApiKey apiKey)
{
    // ...
}
```

**Update**

Looks like this is still having problems with route selection and overloading, especially when some of the parameters are nullable and the value is null. I'm going to have to keep looking into this.

**Update #2**

I managed to simplify the value provider stuff a lot, after finding there is a built-in `NameValuePairValueProvider`